# Visual studio 22 slow Build time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, asp.net-core-6.0

we are working on a project with asp.net core 6 using Visual studio 22 and the build process stuck in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
```

the build done successfuly ,but its slow . build time about 1 minute and 30 seconds.
how to reduce build process time?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'd better collect MSBuild binary log to learn more about the time spent, https://msbuildlog.com and if it also confirms that C# compilation takes too long, at least it gives you the arguments used and you can then reproduce the slowness and troubleshoot further.

Comment: @LexLi the MSBuild Log Viewer shows that Csc ( CoreCompile ) takes 1:22 from 1:30

Answer (score 2):

I am working on Blazor in vs2022 and every change requires recompilation or partial-compilation (hot reload) which was painfully slow.

The following changes I recommend for speeding up build times.

**CPU**

Get a processor with high turbo clock rate, around 4GHZ-5GHZ.
If you are running a laptop, try get an Intel processor that ends with the H letter. For example, the latest Intel CPUs are 12700H/12900H. These are insanely fast laptop processors which can outperform many desktop CPUs.

Ensure your computer is using the Windows Performance profile or equivalent so that your CPU is not being throttled to save power.

**DISK**

First prize is a 4th GEN NVME drive paired with a computer that supports GEN4 NVME. Second prize is any NVME drive.

**ENCRYPTION**

First prize is not to use disk encryption, but if you do need it, opt for hardware encryption as software encryption will consume CPU resources leaving less for compiling. Hardware encryption uses the SSD's own internal encryption (which is always active) to handle the encryption.

My own testing has resulted in +- 40% loss in write performance with software encryption.

**RAM**

Just make sure you have enough RAM and Windows is not swapping memory to disk in order to compile your project. So most often 16GB RAM is sufficient, but I personally prefer to have 32GB so that more is cached by Windows in memory.

**VS2022**

Disable visual studio analyzers during build. Some have reported build times increase when this is turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and turning off the analyzers during the build resolved it.  Right click on the project and select properties.  Then click Code Analysis, and uncheck the box.  [image]