How to prioritize C# project building in VS2022
I have a C# .NET Core web application solution consisting of 127 projects.
Some of them are smaller, built faster (less than 3s), some of them last longer (more than 45s).
Unfortunately, some of those long lasting are built at the end, without obvious reason.
For example, the project lasting 45s seconds is built as 111th out of 127 and this causes 30+s delay before the last project (this one has dependency on the slow one) can be build.
The slow one has direct/indirect dependencies only on 17 other project, so I would like to force the VS2022 to start building it as soon as those 17 are done.
I am running 16 parallel builds so it would be great to make some cores busy with the big projects and let the small ones build in parallel.
From the VS perspective, it does not matter if it is built as 18th or 111th, but starting with that project too late means directly prolong total built time. The same applies to other bigger projects from this solution.
Sum of build times of all those 127 projects divided by degree of parallelism shows that without those delays due to larger projects built too lately total built time of the solution could be 40% shorter.
So is there any flag, setting trick that would let me force VS to prepare build sequence in a way that these priority projects (and their dependencies) are built sooner and remaining projects in a "random" order honoring dependencies?
I tried to add artificial build dependency to other projects on this project to postpone their build and make VS choose the slow one sooner.
If the dependency was too restrictive, this slow project was built as 70th but other projects were waiting for this one so delay was still there and CPU was not fully utilized.
If the dependency was not so restrictive, VS build smaller projects too early and the delay was there.
Even manual editing of the solution file and reordering the project (without modifying any dependencies) has an impact on the ordering and the mentioned project builds after some modification as 90th, after other modification as 103rd. But I could not find any clue how my edits of sln file impact build order.

You can set explicit build dependencies (possible dupe), but I don't know if that breaks your rule of "without modifying any dependencies".

Would it be an option to have some "less frequently" changing projects as DLL dependencies or Nuget packages? So that the solution contains fewer projects.

@gunr2171 This approach is acceptable for me, but as I wrote, I tried it and did not managed to find to proper balance. I either made on my problematic project dependent a project which was referenced by many others and all of them were waiting for problematic one. Or chose a project which was not so often referenced and this did not pushed the problematic one high enough to be build soon enough. Best what I gained was 70th position, but with many other projects waiting then, so build stopped running parallel until the problematic project was built.

@Martin technically it would be possible, although not very natural due to nature of those projects. This solution contains 9 business modules running as one web application and each module contains project for web api, module contract, module DB model, shared module contract for services available to other modules, EF mapping of the DB model, DB services contract for DB layer stored procedure wrappers, DB layer stored procedure wrappers implementation and heavy module implementation project. So it is quite hard to say, which of those would be natural to become nuget packages.

Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76468677/4424024

@Martin: disabling analyzers really significantly reduce build time, but that also means, that "for less money I get less service". Ordering of project did not changed, still built as 103rd, everything done just much faster, so also delay is lower. I was hoping there is a way to tell VS, that ordering projects for build is not based just on dependencies, but also on something else that I can possibly use to prioritize.

You can use the MSBuild command-line tool to make custom builds and control the order in which your projects are built in the following way:

Cleanup Solution:
msbuild YourSolution.sln /t:Clean

Start by building a high-priority project and its dependencies:
msbuild YourSolution.sln /t:ProjectA
msbuild YourSolution.sln /t:ProjectB

Build the rest of the project:
msbuild YourSolution.sln



This seems to be nice approach. Not so comfortable as hitting build button in VS. Is it possible to automate it somehow? Either by some .targets file or some section in sln file that would be applied when Build solution button is hit.

It's suggested that you can apply for a DC feature request and comment me the web link of your request here. @hrontos

I challenged a bit this approach. It gives me full control on build order, but either ends as concurrent builds of the same dependencies (if I run build of all my priority projects in parallel) or if msbuild is invoked sequentially for my priority (large) projects, build time gets longer. Because larger project dependencies are build in parallel, but then large project is build alone, CPU is not fully utilized because it is not preparing dependencies for next large project. Final build time is actually slightly longer than sum of build times of the large projects.

Have you tried to apply for a DC feature request and are there any further debugging feedbacks?@hrontos

Any feedback? @hrontos
